# Showing that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 g_n = \int_0^1 g. $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, riemann-integration

> Let $g_n$ and $g$ be uniformly bounded on $[0,1]$, meaning that there
>   exists a single $M > 0$ satisfying $|g(x)| \leq M$ and $|g_n(x)| \leq
>  M$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in [0,1]$. Assume $g_n
>  \rightarrow g$ pointwise on $[0,1]$ and uniformly on any set of the
>   form $[0, \alpha]$ where $0 < \alpha < 1$. If all the functions are
>   (Riemann) integrable, show that $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 g_n =
>  \int_0^1 g. $

I tried proving this, but I'm not sure if my reasoning is entirely correct. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Fix $\alpha \in (0,1)$ and consider the interval $[0, \alpha]$. Then $$ \left| \int_0^1 g_n - \int_0^1 g \right| \\ = \left| \int_0^{\alpha} g_n + \int_{\alpha}^1 g_n - \left( \int_0^{\alpha} g + \int_{\alpha}^1 g \right) \right| \\ \leq \int_{0}^{\alpha} | g_n(x) - g(x) | dx + \int_{\alpha}^1 |g_n(x) - g(x)| dx \\ \leq \int_{0}^{\alpha} | g_n(x) - g(x) | dx + \int_{\alpha}^1 |g_n(x)| dx + \int_{\alpha}^1 |g(x)| dx. $$  Since $g_n \rightarrow g$ uniform on $[0, \alpha]$, there exists a $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$ |g_n(x) - g(x)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2 \alpha}, $$  for all $x \in [a,b]$ and all $n \geq n_0$. Since $g_n$ and $g$ are uniformly bounded, we have $|g_n(x)| < M$ and $|g(x)| < M$. So all together this would give me $$ \left| \int_0^1 g_n - \int_0^1 g \right| < \frac{\epsilon}{2\alpha} + 2M(1-\alpha). $$ How can I get this smaller than $\epsilon$? Also, I'm not sure if my reasoning is correct since I haven't used the fact that $g_n \rightarrow g$ pointwise on $[0,1]$.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Are your functions continous ?

Comment: That is not given. All is given, is that they are Riemann integrable.

Comment: If $|g_n(x) - g(x)| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2\alpha}$ then $\int_0^\alpha|g_n(x) - g(x)|dx \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$, not $\frac{\epsilon}{2\alpha}$. Then your bound is $\frac{\epsilon}{2} + 2M(1-\alpha)$, so by choosing $\alpha$ small enough, you're done

Comment: Why do you still have $\alpha$ in the denominator after "So all together this would give me"? And since you can choose the $\alpha$ you want to use, to control the second term have you, for instance,  tried to set $\alpha\stackrel{\rm def}{=} 1-\frac{\varepsilon}{4M}$?

Comment: (Also, the pointwise convergence does not seem necessary, to answer your doubt. Note that the uniform convergence you get imply already $f_n\to f$ pointwise on $[0,1)$; and the convergence pointwise at $1$ is not useful nor necessary for the result you want.)

Comment: Now let $\alpha \to 1$.

Comment: I'm confused. I don't know if I can pick $\alpha =  1 - \frac{\epsilon}{4M}$. How am I guaranteed that $\alpha > 0$?

Comment: @YannHamdaoui, I was thinking of that too but why is it that OP can just choose the $\alpha$?  From the description it sounds like this needs to hold for all $\alpha \in (0,1)$, not just $\alpha$ arbitrarily close to $1$.

Comment: CC @ClementC. also

Comment: @Kamil: You can assume that without loss of generality if $\frac{\varepsilon}{4M} \not\in(0,1)$, take $\varepsilon$ smaller.

Comment: @tilper The fact that it holds for all $\alpha \in (0,1)$ is an hypthesis, I don't have to prove it. What I have to prove, is that the difference $|\int g_n - \int g|$ is arbitrary close to $0$, for $n$ big enough. To do so, I can use the hypothesis with wichever $\alpha$ please me.

Comment: @tilper This is the **assumption**. You are *given* the uniform convergence on $[0,\alpha]$ for any $\alpha\in(0,1)$. Therefore, you can choose to apply it to any $\alpha$ you like, there is nothing to prove there.

Comment: @Kamil, you can pick $M$ and $\epsilon$ so that $1 - \frac{\epsilon}{4M} > 0$.  $M$ doesn't need to be a tight upper bound, and regardless of $M$ you can choose $\epsilon < 4M$ so that $\frac{\epsilon}{4M} < 1$.

Comment: @YannHamdaoui, right, derp, now that I read it again it's so obvious.  Thanks.

Comment: CC @ClementC. also

Comment: Alright, thank you guys. I understand now. And the $\alpha$ can be anything I think, since it is given that convergence is uniform on ANY set of the form $[0, \alpha]$. The problem is from 'Understanding Analysis' by Abbott.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: You're so close. Take $\alpha$ close to $1$. Then we can bound the difference of the integrals on $[0, \alpha]$ since it is uniform. Then we can bound the difference of the integrals by $2M(1 - \alpha)$, as you have done: since $\alpha$ is close to $1$, this quantity will also be small.

Comment: Can you be more specific please. Like write down explicitly the last steps of the argumentations? Since I still don't know how to pick $\alpha$ to get the correct upper bound.

Comment: Let $1 - \alpha < \frac{\varepsilon}{2M}$. Then (Using your last line) we have $\frac{\varepsilon}{2\alpha} + M(1 - \alpha) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} = \varepsilon$.

Comment: @MichaelTong You are missing a factor $2$ in the last line. (Also, there shouldn't be any $\alpha$ in the denominator.)

Comment: @ClementC. You mean in the answer or the comment? In the comment I was just leaving off where Kamil started, though I agree there shouldn't be an $\alpha$ in the denominator of $\frac{\varepsilon}{2 \alpha}$

Comment: Yes -- there was a mistake in the original post, better to correct it than to go silently with it.